# Amazon S3 server side encryption of already loaded files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have uploaded some files to Amazon S3 using my program. Now I want enable server side encryption for all these files after they are already loaded to s3.

Is there a way to enable it using some property from the Amazon Console itself, so that all files use server side encryption? (I don't want to set property file by file as I have too many of these).

The other way I think would be to do it programmatically, download all files, and then upload again with encryption set. I really want to avoid this, unless there is no easier way.

I have explored s3 bucket policy a little bit but didn't find how to enable for data that is already loaded into s3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do this file-by-file, but you don't have to download and re-upload. Just issue a copy command for each file with the same source and destination, but with the encryption flag enabled.

Comment: thanks for your answer!! I think this will work. I have a follow up question, how can I list all the files that have encryption enabled (as in my bucket, I have files that are unencrypted and also some files that are encrytped). I looked `ls` page but it seems not possible using the cli http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html . If there is no way then I will list all then copy all files but would want to avoid that.

Comment: You could list the files, then query the metadata for each file to see if they are encrypted, but that probably won't be any faster than just running the copy command on each file.